# Swift: Programmatically set a view before first line of UICollectionViewController

Tags: uicollectionview

a bit confused reading in the Apple documentation, tried multiple settings but no luck so far, so I hope to have a response here.

I am implementing a UICollectionViewController with header and vertical scrolling.
All work flawlessy but now I want to add a view in which I want to put an TabBar below the header and before the first line of the collectionview.

I want also that the tabBar moves when scrolling so i can't just add a subview and let it disapper once the scroll starts.

I suppose I have to set the spacing for the first line to be big enough and once done create a view, add the subview and create the tabbar inside of it.

Now the question , which sections of those I have to override? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach will be to implement the view to be added as the first cell of collection view.

Comment: If you could update the response with an example would be great. Thanks.